# How can I verify if a string exists in a cell, and if not, add it, as part of a larger loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a sheet and add a number to the column "Codes", if it isn't already there,(along with highlighting all 3 cells in the row in red) given a certain condition holds (Column C/Column B > .8). (Given the below, I'd want to add the Code "4" anywhere that C/B > .80 and '4' isn't already in Codes.)

```
   Codes    B          C
    1       100       90
    2       100       95
            100       82
    6       100       70
    4       100       85
```

I have tried the following:

```
Public Sub Testing()
Dim ValA    As Range
Dim ValB    As Range
Dim ValC    As Range
Dim ColA    As Long
Dim ColB    As Long
Dim ColC    As Long
Dim i       As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Set Variables
Set ValA = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("Codes", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not ValA Is Nothing Then
    ColA = ValA.Column
End If

Set ValB = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("B", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not ValB Is Nothing Then
    ColB = ValB.Column
End If

Set ValC = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("C", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not ValC Is Nothing Then
    ColC = ValC.Column
End If

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'loop
'Since you cant have any 0's in a division calc:
If ColC > 0 And ColB > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Value < 1 Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB) = "N/A" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Value > ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Value * 0.8 Then
            If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value.Find("4", lookat:=xlPart) Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value & " 4"

            End If
        End If
    Next i
Else: MsgBox "Matches werent found for B and C"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering and on what line?

Comment: As a side note, you could omit `ActiveSheet` prefix before `Cells` for the sake of readability, because when you use just `Cells` you automatically refer to active sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner "Object Required" on the line  "If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value.Find("4", lookat:=xlPart) Then"

Comment: @JohnyL for the love of pete that is terrible advice.  One should always set the parent sheet regardless.

Comment: @ScottCraner Counter point noted as well!

Comment: Add `Is Nothing` before the `Then` on that statement

Comment: @ScottCraner Perhaps, this is terrible for you, but I prefer simplicity. The polluted code is a nighmare to read. If you write in C#, I hope you don't write `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` __every time__ you use SqlConnection? Or `System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Same error

Comment: I am talking about vba, When using vba in Excel one should ***Always*** declare the parent of all Range Objects.  If you want clean looking, use `With` Blocks and worksheet variables. @JohnyL

Comment: Change it to `If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value <> 4 then`

Comment: Maybe change it to Activesheet.Cells(i,ColA).Find("4", LookIn:=xlValues,.LookAt:=xlPart)

Comment: @JohnyL the issue comes when the code get longer and more complicated with multiple sheets, many times the user by switching sheets can screw up the execution.  If you are the only one using the code, because you understand what needs to be active during the run, or if the code is on the worksheet code sheet and not a module leaving it off would not cause problems.

Comment: @ScottCraner You say __always__, but it's not clear why OP __must__ follow your **not so good** advice. The readability of code is worse with senseless prefixing with ActiveSheet. This just distracts reader (and writer too) from code. I ain't gonna assure you why your advice is bad, so I think this is the spot to stop.

Comment: @JohnyL implicit activesheet references are the cause of the bug behind about one in three VBA questions asked on this site every day. Readability means code that says what it does, and does what it says. Unqualified `Cells` property accessor calls do different things depending on whether you're in a worksheet module or a standard or class module. This isn't about qualifying the namespace, it's about qualifying the parent object, which is an implicit hidden `_Global` module if omitted. Scott is correct.

Comment: @ScottCraner It may have other codes in the Codes column i.e (1,3,5,4) and therefore I don't think <>4 will work. It could be (4,3,2) and your code would add 4 again to that no?

Comment: Okay `IF Instr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Value,"4")=0 then`

Comment: @Mat'sMug So, when I use Cells in sheet module, I do understand that it refers to sheet *in question*, but when you use ActiveSheet, then you really mean active sheet - whichever happens to be active. As for Scott Craner's offering to use With construction - this, too, adds complexity to code as you should track what empty dot means. That's why, I guess, it was left out in JavaScript in ES6+ and is not implemented in C#.

Comment: @JohnyL *You* understand it. Many, *many* rookies don't. The specific quirks and implementation details of a given API/object model add to the cognitive load of the code - hence explicit code that *does what it says and says what it does* is preferable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I will disappoint you, but ActiveSheet.Cells is **NOT enough**, too! Guess, why!